# Bundler and Rails looking at different gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This has driven me crazy.  I changed laptop and tried getting my Rails environment working again.  Mac OS X has its own ruby, but I used brew and installed new.  I installed rails 3.0.5, ran:

```
bundle install
```

Then:

```
rails s
```

I got this error:

```
Could not find aws-s3-0.6.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After bashing my head against a wall for a couple hours, I tried just manually installing the gems and it worked!  So, apparently, rails and bundler are looking at different places for my gems.  Both are from my brew install.

How can I figure out what each is looking at so I can use "bundle install" again?

Answer (score 0):

Rails and Bundle are looking at the gems providing they are in the bundle.

Use the

```
bundle show
```

command to see the gems Rails is having access to via bundler.

Also you can examine the Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: Perhaps I don't get it.  How come when I run bundle install and it says everything installed does it fail when I run rails?  Why did I have to get the gems manually?

Answer (score 0):

The gemfile sources mainly from rubygems.org as supposed to rubyforge (which came up when i searched that gem on google). I think the gem command will check both. You can specify additional sources, as mentioned in the readme: http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html

Comment: bundler didn't report any issues getting the gems...?

Comment: Did it say the gem was installed as well? If so, you might need to file an issue on the bundler repository.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pow? I've been having this issue with Pow starting up with one version of ruby, but not the version that I have RVM currently set to.

I have not tried it yet, but [this issue on Github](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/119) mentions the problem and refers people to the Pow trouble shooting [here](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Troubleshooting). I've pasted the contents below:

## RVM

Incorrect ruby or gemset is being used

Create a .rvmrc at your project root. See [rvmrc docs](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/).

System-wide RVM install

If you have a system-wide RVM install and are getting the error `LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/setup`, run `rvm info` to find out where rvm is installed on your machine, then do this:

```
echo "export POW_RVM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.powconfig
```

Where `/usr/local/rvm/` is the location of your rvm installation.

Then restart POW by killing it in the Activity Monitor or in Terminal.

Comment: Not running POW nor RVM (anymore).

Comment: If you're not running RVM, you'll need be be doing `sudo bundle install`.